# Same Alias Routes For Multi Users Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two users, if they are logged in it should appear a different dashboard for each users. I want the routes url not shown as function's name but custom name such as `/dasboard` or more like this `http://localhost/project/dashboard/` for the two of them (users). for that I tried to set on `Routes.php` like this below:

```
$route['dashboard'] = 'admin/index';
$route['dashboard'] = 'user/index';
```

But the result not displaying anything for user/index route, did I make a mistake or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

when the user logs in, set a session value of which group they belong to, e.g.:
`$_SESSION['group']='admin';` or `$_SESSION['group']='user';`

now, in your [routes](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html), your 2nd route has no effect, as

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will
> always take precedence over lower ones.

but you can make them dynamic, checking your [sessions](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html):

```
if( isset($_SESSION['group']) && $_SESSION['group']=='admin'){
  $route['dashboard'] = 'admin/index';  // logged in as admin
}elseif( isset($_SESSION['group']) && $_SESSION['group']=='user'){
  $route['dashboard'] = 'user/index';  // logged in as user
}else{
  $route['dashboard'] = 'login';  // not logged in, send to login 
}
```

Comment: i have replace ['group'] with my set_userdata and used code above only one parameter (Not use param after &&), but its displaying 404 Page Not Found

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['group'])` checks if session parameter exists and `&& $_SESSION['group']=='admin'` checks if the session parameter is *admin*. If you omit it, it won't work. You most likely come into the else clause and as you might not have a controller login defined yet, you get the 404 error

Comment: i've used two parameters again and yes i have defined it in controller login with `redirect('dashboard');` but still 404 Page Not Found

Comment: check if you are following all naming rules (capitalized class names, capitalized filenames for controllers and models. Also if you call a view file in your controller, which doesn't exist: 404, and if your baseurl is set wrong, 404, or if your system/application settings in your route index.php are wrong: 404